# Branch.io link not opening in safari but opening in chrome

Tags: android, ios, deep-linking, branch.io

I just implemented branch.io deep linking in my android and ios application . The link is opening perfectly in android , however as and when the link is shared from android to ios, the safari opens the link and displays -"Cannot open the page because the address is invalid". I am able to open the same link in the ios from the chrome and it successfully shows me the apple store link. Could some developer from branch.io please guide me through a legitimate solution and help me with the fix. Thanks in advance

Comment: Alex from Branch.io here: we'll need a bit more info to debug. Let's start with an example link that isn't working as expected, and we can take it from there :)

Answer (score 0):

I submitted a ticket for this too, my links worked from my landing page for all platforms I tested except Mac Desktop with Safari.

This worked for me in the meantime - although I would prefer the link opening in the same tab.

Add `target="_blank"` to your link,

`<a href="link/to/branch target="_blank" />`

This opens the branch link in a new tab, and the link directs to my SMS-landingpage.